# Installing Netgear AC600 (model no a6100) Wireless AC Adapter on 16.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 16.04, realtek-wireless, netgear

I just switched my laptop off of Windows 10 onto Ubuntu 16.04 and my internal wlan device no longer works! I went on a Ubuntu help IRC last night and was essentially told the the Broadcom device inside is quite difficult to fanangle into working on Ubuntu. So I went and bought a WLAN Dongle which I was under the impression would work as before I purchased it I found [this](http://www.humans-enabled.com/2016/03/how-to-ubuntu-1604-gnu-linux-netgear.html) guide on how to get it working - great! Well, I walked my way through the installation process and got the the very last step which is `$ sudo modprobe 8812au` and I get an error. That error is: `mobprobe: ERROR: could not insert '8812au': Required key not available`. I have no idea how to fix this. When I cd into the dir that I git-cloned earlier on in the steps I see 6 different files that include `8812au` in their names.

When I have it plugged in and execute `lsusb` it does display.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! If you need any other information please let me know.

Comment: I checked out dual band adapters a couple of years ago to use with Linux and they weren't well received then. I just googled it again and they still don't seem promising. An inexpensive Intel 2.4 Ghz single band seems to work best, or at least it has for me to-date. Hopefully some dual-band users will respond with positive answers for you. 8812AU = dual band. Having to compile specialized drivers to use a WiFi adapter doesn't make sense to me. The mfg should provide the driver if it really works. IMO.

Comment: That seems like such a silly solution though doesn't it?

Comment: @brasbonanza. It seems like a comment. A solution would be posted in the Answer section. Your comment seems silly.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running a 64 bit UEFI system, I believe you are being bitten by the recent change that more strictly enforces Secure Boot.  If you turn off Secure Boot you should be able to perform the step that is failing.

Comment: My interface was ok then one day stopped working:   This solution worked for me. Strangely fastboot is re-enabled automatically  from time to  time (6 month or so)